# How do I target an  <a> inside a   <div>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have this code : http://jsfiddle.net/Qchmqs/BSKrG/

```
<div class="step"><-- this is darned wrong
    <div id="step2"><a>Darn</a></div>
    <div id="step2"><a>Darn</a></div>
    <div id="step2"><a>Darn</a></div>
</div>
<div class="step"><-- this works fine
    <div id="step2"><a>Darn</a>
    <a>Darn</a>
    <a>Darn</a></div>
</div>
```

The first block is three links inside  three separate divs inside a surrounding div

The bottom block has the links inside one parent div

I am trying to change the background of an active link, but it won't turn off in the upper block.

The script works well with the bottom links but not working as expected with the upper ones

PS : The active class should be toggled only from the Links i have a lot of other scripts in the page that uses the .active links from this list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, do what JamesJohnson said and remove the multiple IDs. They can only cause you problems down the road.

In the upper links, the `a` tags aren't siblings because you put each one in its own `div`. So you need to do this to remove classes from the other `a`s:

```
$(this).parent().siblings('div').children('a').removeClass('active');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/BSKrG/1/

Unfortunately, that breaks the functionality on the lower links. You can achieve success in both places by adding `andSelf` to the parent siblings:

```
$(this).parent().siblings('div').andSelf().children('a').removeClass('active');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/BSKrG/2/

Comment: i will rewrite the down links in another way cuz i know exactly how to, the only problem i had u just solved it out

Answer (score 1):

It's not working on the upper ones because you're assigning the same `id` to the divs. You should probably use the class attribute instead:

```
<div class="step2"><a>Damn</a></div>
<div class="step2"><a>Damn</a></div>
<div class="step2"><a>Damn</a></div>
```

After making the above changes, you should be able to do this:

```
$(".step2 a").text("Hello World!");
```

Comment: sorry but i can't change any thing in the uppers html

Answer (score 0):

maybe this:

```
<div class="step">
    <div id="step2"><a>Damn</a>
    <a>Damn</a>
    <a>Damn</a></div>
</div>
<div class="step">
    <div id="step2"><a>Damn</a>
    <a>Damn</a>
    <a>Damn</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: actually i asked this question because i can't edit the dom structure it will destroy the style of the page so i need to have the same effect of the down link on the upper links without changing the HTMl

Answer (score 0):

Using radio inputs you can create this effect without any JS at all, which degrades gracefully from its intended appearance (a red backgrounded "damn") to damn with radios next to it (sending the same information).
ironically, this example at JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YvQdj/

My memory is a bit fuzzy, but I'm pretty sure this doesn't work in older versions of IE without some finagling.

Comment: i can't change the structure of the html

Comment: Oh, so you're stuck with multiple instances of that id? I'm so sorry.